# SSE: Should I set a shuffle mask as static variable or not?

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics

If in a function I need a fixed shuffle mask, should I set it as `const` or `static const`?

```
const __m128i SHUFFLE_MASK = _mm_setr_epi8(0,  4,  8, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                                           -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);

static const __m128i SHUFFLE_MASK = _mm_setr_epi8(0,  4,  8, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                                                  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ semantics of \`static const\` vs \`const\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709207/c-semantics-of-static-const-vs-const)

Comment: @Adriano I don't know if it is a real difference, but I am using a function to initialize the variable, not a constant. As a side note, the function is not a static function.

Comment: If function is static or not IMO doesn't matter (as it doesn't matter if you're using a function or literal values, it's not a constexpr). Anyway I'd use static const because at first sight you do that computation once (but here a compiler can be much clever than what we expect so an inspection to generated code may be more useful than my guessing).

Comment: I agree with Adriano - check the generated code.  In my case, a static const variable was much worse because g++ generated code to check if the variable was set each time.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `_mm_setr_epi8` of compile-time-constant data ends up compiling to a 16B chunk of read-only data that gets loaded (or used as a memory operand).  (look for labels like `.LC0` in the `gcc -S` asm output).  This is already optimal.

Emil Styrke commented that `static const` can end up including code to check if the static location is already initialized.  Since there's no benefit, and a possible cost (at least on older gcc, haven't checked myself), avoid `static const` for vectors (esp. when the declaration and initializer is inside a function).

IDK if gcc ever optimizes a `setr` that has a pattern in the data into a `movd` and shuffle, or something like that.  If so, then you might potentially want to avoid generating your constant with instructions, instead of having it there as a memory operand.

This seems like a very unlikely case, though.  But if you need to defeat such an optimization, you can probably do it using a static (file-scope) `char` array to hold your constant, and casting a pointer to a vector type.