# What is the difference of const and static const?

Tags: c++

The following statements are both valid:

```
static const A = 2;
const B = 3;
```

What is the difference of declaring the first or the second?

Comment: This was already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709207/c-semantics-of-static-const-vs-const

Comment: Chances are some questions that appeared while you were writing this answered your question.

Comment: @yu-hao **Nope @guys!** Both of the dupes to follow are marked [tag:c]!! There actually are differences that need explanation; voted to reopen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709207/c-semantics-of-static-const-vs-const would be a more appropriate dupe.

Comment: @vin%c3%adcius-gobbo-a-de-oliveira You should clarify scope of these snippets.

Comment: @devnull While I wrote my question only questions regarding the differences between `static` and `const` came up. That's why I proceeded to open the question. Thank you all for pointing the dupplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If the `static` const were to be declared inside a class it'd accesible from the class and any instance of the class, so all of the would share the same value; and the const alone will be exclusive for every instance of the class.

Given the class:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        static const int A = 2;
        const int B = 4;
};
```

You can do this:

```
int main() {
    printf("%d", MyClass::A);

    /* Would be the same as */

    MyClass obj;
    printf("%d", obj.A);

    /* And this would be illegal */
    printf("%d", MyClass::B);
}
```

Check it out [here on Ideone](http://ideone.com/olBKn1).

Comment: What's with the unnecessary usage of new? That also isn't how you access `A` in `obj`.

Comment: Sorry I got that messed up, let me fix that.

Comment: @Rapptz sorry I confused your comment with the static field.

Comment: It still won't compile. Drop the unnecessary and erroneous `new`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry for the delay, it's done. I missed `int` too.

Answer (score 0):

Static means the entire class only shares 1 const, where non-static means every instance of the class has that const individually.

Example:

```
class A{

static const a;
const b; 
}

//Some other place:

A m;
A n;
```

Objects m and n have the same a, but different b.