# Class scope constants: const vs static const

Tags: c++

For constants of a class, should I use class scope static const, or file scope const?

For example:

```
// .h
class C {
  private:
    static const int some_constant_c;
}

// .cc
const C::some_constant_c = 10;
```

vs.

```
// .h
class C {
}

// .cc
const some_constant_c = 10;
```

To me, the former one have better semantic meaning that the constant is of a certain class, but the latter one have the advantage not exposing constants to header file.

==============

One follow up question on this:

What if I want my constants be accessed by subclasses. Make sense to put `static const` in `protected`? Example follows:

```
// .h
class C {
  protected:
    static const int some_constant_c;
}
```

Comment: Use object scope const.

Comment: You should read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3709257/4793675

Comment: @user3528438 Care to share more?

Comment: Non-static const is object scope. It can be initialized to different values for different instances of the class in the constructor's initializer list.

Comment: @Ricardo Thanks for pointing to me this answer, which I did read. However, I'm struggling between `static const` in class declaration or source file.

Comment: @user3528438 I'm not struggling between class scope or object scope `const`, but `static const` in class declaration or source file. Note that `const` in source file is indeed `static const` in c++.

Comment: Follow-Up question: yes, in this case it should be the member of the class. There is no other (obvious/simple/not IOCCC) way to expose the constants to derived classes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer 2nd variant, provided the const in the 1st case is private.

Why should one pollute the class declaration with redundant information?
Consider, you are implementing a protocol parser, with many many constants. How will the class declaration look like?

Another issue is, why should you type the name of the const twice? I try to keep definition and initialization as close as possible.

Just an opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer! Mind to have a look at my follow up question?

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of personal preference, of course. Trying not to expose class internals in the header file is a ship that has most definitely sailed in C++... between member variables and private member functions, it's just not practical to keep implementation details out of the header (unless you're using the pImpl idiom).

If all you want is to hide the *value* of the constant, note that you can put the initializer in the source file instead.

If you do implement the constants as globals in the source file, use an anonymous namespace to keep them from causing linker collisions.

Comment: " use an anonymous namespace to keep them from causing linker collisions." - If they are defined in .cc as in the question, they won't cause linker collision.

Comment: "If all you want is to hide the value of the constant, note that you can put the initializer in the source file instead." - It is actually what he did :-)

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer! Mind to have a look at my follow up question?