# Why is multiple definition of a const global variable allowed in C++ and not in C?

Tags: c++, c, constants, one-definition-rule

Multiple definition of a global variable is not allowed in C or C++ due to the One Definition Rule. However, in C++ a const global variable can be defined in multiple compilation units with no error. This is not the same as in C.

Why does C++ allow this while C does not? Why does the usage and behaviour of a const global differ from a non-const global in this way in C++ compared to C? What is happening under the covers with C++ and C with respect to const?

For example this is allowed in C++, but wrong in C:

```
// Foo.cpp
const int Foo = 99;

// Main.cpp
const int Foo = 99;
int main()
{
    cout << Foo << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is fine with C, but wrong with C++:

```
// Foo.cpp
const int Foo = 99;

// Main.cpp
extern const int Foo;
int main()
{
    cout << Foo << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question...?  Which part are you confused about?

Comment: I guess he is confused about the fact that he cannot declare a const int as extern without getting linking errors.

Comment: Merlyn: I know how to use const in C++. I am interested to know why const was designed like this and not like a normal global variable?

Comment: Arguably, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c

Answer (score 28):

```
// Foo.cpp
const int Foo = 99;

// Main.cpp
const int Foo = 99;
```

`const` variable at namespace scope has *internal* linkage. So they're basically two different variables.  There is no redefinition.

From @David's comment, 3.5/3 [basic.link]:

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.5)
>   has **internal linkage** if it is the name
>   of
>   — an object, reference, function or
>   function template that is explicitly
>   declared static or,
>   — an object or
>   reference that is **explicitly declared
>   const and neither explicitly declared
>   extern nor previously declared to have
>   external linkage**; or
>   — a data member
>   of an anonymous union.

---

In the second case, you should be doing this (correct way):

```
//Foo.h
extern const int Foo; //use extern here to make it have external linkage!

// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
const int Foo = 99; //actual definition goes here

// Main.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
int main()
{
   cout << Foo << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nawaz. Is this explained somewhere in the C++ Programming Language book or some other reference?

Comment: In the standard... 3.5/3 [basic.link]: *A name having namespace scope (3.3.5) has internal linkage if it is the name of
— an object, reference, function or function template that is explicitly declared static or,— **an object or reference that is explicitly declared const and neither explicitly declared extern nor
previously declared to have external linkage;** or — a data member of an anonymous union.*

Comment: @David: I quoted your comment in my post. I was looking for this text in the Standard after @Ashwin's request, but you made the job easy. Hope you don't mind it.

Comment: I think should include `Foo.h` in `Foo.cpp` too, otherwise `Foo` is not declared with external linkage.

Comment: @Matthieu: True. I just forgot to do that. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

I think you are asking for the rationale and not the specific language rule that allows this.

The rationale for this is that it makes `const` variables much easier to use. It gives a typed replacement for one common use of `#define`.

Instead of `#define MAX_COUNT 211` you can use `const int max_count = 211;` in exactly the same way, e.g. a shared header file, without having to worry about where to put the one definition.

You can't legally change the value of a `const` object so there's no visible difference between having one object and multiple objects with the same value.

As you can put a definition of a `const` object in a header file it makes trivial for the compiler to use the value directly at the compilation stage without such optimizations having to be delayed to a link-time fixup.

Comment: Could you also explain why this C++ behaviour of const differs from C? The code above that works in C++ has multiple-definition error in C!

Comment: @Ashwin: I'm afraid not. I believe that C had more backwards compatibility issues (supporting tentative definitions?) and have ended up with a more compromised `const` but I don't have any direct evidence for this.

Comment: @AshwinNanjappa I suppose C just prefers to keep keyword usage consistent in this case - if you specify static, you get internal linkage; otherwise, you get external linkage :)

Answer (score 6):

Basically, in C++, const, non-local variables are genuine constant expressions, or constexpr. This permits plenty of things, like TMP.

```
const int five = 5;
int main() {
    int x[five];
    std::array<int, five> arr;
}
```

In C, they are just a variable that cannot be modified. That is,

```
const int five = 5;
int main() {
    int x[five]; // Technically, this is a variable length array
}
```

Is quite equivalent to

```
int five = 5;
int main() {
    int x[five];
}
```

Effectively, C++ promotes some kinds of `const` variable to a new category, `constexpr`, whereas in C, this does not exist and they are just variables which happen to be unmodifiable.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like *const* [doesn't actually generate an external symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c).

Comment: Yes, this behaviour is different from C! You have shown another aspect of this confusion :-)

Answer (score -1):

*Why do English people spell COLOUR, whereas American people spells it COLOR?*

They are 2 different languages from the same base, but they don't have the same rules.

C & C++ are the same.  If they weren't different, they would both be called the same thing.

Comment: "why are they different?" "Because they're not the same!" Not useful.

Answer (score -3):

My workaround was declaring it as :

```
static classfoo foo;
```

it worked in my situation.