# Typedef Variables for Global Use?

Tags: c++, global, typedef

Suppose we have source file wide this decl:

```
typedef VOID ( NTAPI *my_RtlInitUnicodeString ) (
PUNICODE_STRING DestinationString,
PCWSTR SourceString
);
my_RtlInitUnicodeString rtlInitUnicodeString;
//static has same effect
```

Any attempt to use rtlInitUnicodeString in the source file internal functions requires "redefining" like this:

```
my_RtlInitUnicodeString rtlInitUnicodeString ....
```

Clicking on "definition" [VS] for rtlInitUnicodeString used in any source file internal functions always takes us to its home: *Winternl.h* instead of the source file wide decl.  Is this a compiler limitation or is there another way rtlInitUnicodeString can be made available for all and sundry?

Comment: Is this C or is this C++?

Comment: C compiled as  C++ code.

Comment: Ok we should remove the C++ tag then as your question refers to C.

Comment: I'm assuming when you say "module wide decl" you mean a C file and not a header file that is included by module code. If that is the case then, as explained in the answer, you need to have an `extern` declaration of the variable wherever it is used. Each seperate C file is a seperate compilation unit and the compiler does not know there is a "module wide decl" unless you explicitly tell it so - via the `extern`.

Comment: If this is C code compiled as C++ you may be running into one of the key differences between C and C++. (Contrary to common usage, there is no such thing as C/C++.) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173872/why-is-multiple-definition-of-a-const-global-variable-allowed-in-c-and-not-in .

Comment: @kaylum: Noted. Only one resource, header and source file used.

Comment: MCVE or it didn't happen.

Comment: Also note that neither C nor C++ have modules. There are source files and header files.

Comment: OK. Give me time to get something at Git. Sorry "module" from my VB days. Edit/replaced "module"/"source file".

Comment: As you compile as C++, this is a C++ question. C and C++ are different languages, please don't treat one as a subset of the other, they aren't.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Take that up with Trevor. maybe a "C compiled as C++" tag? Do you imply there is no difference between "C compiled as C++" and "C++ compiled as C++"?

Comment: @LaurieStearn Both are C++ code. If you write C code, compile with a C compiler. Yes, some C code also compiles with a C++ compiler but in general the semantics are different and you run into odd issues.

Comment: You should post an MCVE; it's hard to fix compile errors without it.  And post the exact compile error you get.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have more than one definition of the variable in your program.  To use a variable from different compilation units, each compilation unit using it should include a header file with a declaration of the variable.  A declaration should start with the keyword "extern".  This is just how global variables work in C, it has nothing to do with typedefs.

Comment: Hmmm, then there is something fishy with this setup. rtlInitUnicodeString is _not_ recognized in the module as described in the question.

Comment: Your question has very little information in it.  My answer is based on an understanding of how global variables work in C and I have used them like this many times.  If you think my answer is wrong, you should post the full  code you are trying to compile (after simplifying it), say exactly how you compile it, and show the exact compiler error you are getting.  More than likely, there is some detail you are overlooking or you made a typo somewhere.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you say how you compile it and post the exact error message you get?

Comment: VS10 Pro Win32 debug F5 using MS symbols. The rest is all in the MCVE proj file. In MCVE.c it always fails with C2365 as described in the comment at the end of line 22. If line 53 is commented out line 54 generates a C2659 as described in the comment at the end of line 54. If both 22 and 53 are commented out, 54 generates a C2659. It's why it should compile without line 22 but with lines 53 and 54 is what the question is about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was not obvious until the compilation error was noted:

```
error C2659: '=' : function as left operand
```

Something got twisted in knots. But an explanation of why

```
my_RtlInitUnicodeString RtlInitUnicodeString = (my_RtlInitUnicodeString) GetProcAddress(hdlNtCreateFile, initUnicodeFnString);
```

works in source-file internal functions but not

```
RtlInitUnicodeString = (my_RtlInitUnicodeString) GetProcAddress(hdlNtCreateFile, initUnicodeFnString);
```

requires an understanding beyond my ken.