# extern const array does not link

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, extern

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does const imply internal linkage in C++, when it doesn’t in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c)

If I have the following:

a.cpp:

```
const int ArrayOfInts[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

b.cpp:

```
extern const int ArrayOfInts[];

void SomeFunc()
{
    int a = ArrayOfInts[0];
}
```

The linker complains that ArrayOfInts is unresolved from b.obj. Removing the const qualifier makes the link succeed. Any ideas why this fails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the compiler compiles `b.cpp`, for all it knows, the value of `ArrayOfInts[0]` could be anything. So it's not a compile-time constant. In C++, constants at file scope are compile-time constants by default.

Comment: You can make a constant at file scope with external linkage by declaring it `extern const`.

Comment: I'll add "by default" to the end of my answer.

Comment: "In C++, constants at file scope are compile-time constants by default." - thought this only applied to simple integer types. Thanks for clarifying.