# global std::string and one definition rule

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

I have a header file that contains the following definition

```
const std::string error[] = {"a", "b"};
```

Now I'm including this file in two different translation units and compiling the source codes. Everything works, but why? This is expected to break `one definition rule`.

Now even more interesting, I'm changing the type

```
const char* error[] = {"a", "b"};
```

and here it is, expected error

```
multiple definition of `error'
```

It works the same way as for std::string for `int`, `char`, `short` and other integral types. What is this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`const` gives *namespace-scoped* variables internal linkage, that's why it works, effectively the same as

```
static const std::string error[] = {"a", "b"};
```

The second one doesn't work because it's not the variable that is const, but the `char`s it consists of.

Comment: Didn't know that const gives an internal linkage. Thanks. Is it mentioned in standard?

Comment: Yes, found it. `Objects declared const and not explicitly declared extern have internal linkage.`

Comment: @axe What's the reference?

Comment: Never mind. It's 7.1.1 Storage class specifiers [dcl.stc], paragraph 7.

Comment: Also note that this is one of the few places where C++ breaks compatibility with C. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c) for details and rationale.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables declared `const` have internal linkage, as if they were also declared `static`. You can define internal variables with the same name in different translation units, so that's what happens in your first example - each unit that includes the header gets its own copy of the array.

The second example is not `const` - the pointers point to constant objects, but are themselves mutable. So this array has external linkage, and is subject to the One Definition Rule.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/357syhfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> In C, constant values default to external linkage, so they can appear only in source files. In C++, constant values default to internal linkage, which allows them to appear in header files.