# Why does 'x' have internal rather than external linkage?

Tags: c++, gcc

Based on my reading of the C++ 2011 spec, I would think that the following code would create a variable 'x' with external linkage in file1.cc.  I would think that I would be able to access that variable from main.cc and therefore that the program would print 'x'.  However, I instead get a linker error for an undefined reference to 'x' from main.cc.  Why does 'x' from file1.cc have internal linkage?  I think the compiler is interpreting section 3.5.3 as giving 'x' internal linkage in file1.cc.  However I have not "explicitly declared" 'x' to be 'const', as that section would require.  I am using g++ version 4.6.3.

main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef const char CC;

extern CC x[];

int main(void) {
  std::cout << x[0] << std::endl;
}
```

file1.cc:

```
typedef const char CC;

CC x[] = "abc";
```

Comment: With gcc-4.8.2 and clang-3.3 and `-std=c++11` both I get an undefined symbol error. The reason is given in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

The `const` makes all the difference. In C++ `const` variables declared at file scope implicitly have internal linkage. This is because in C++ const values can be used as compile-time constants (which leave nothing to link to).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/998457/321772).

You can add `extern` to your definition in file1.cc to explicitly specify external linkage for `x`:

```
extern CC x[] = "abc";
```

Comment: `x` has been explicitly declared as `extern`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, only in `main.cc`.