# How to include constants in my project

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt-project I have some classes (.h and .cpp files). In some of them i use different constants and functions. There are some constants, that I use in 2 or 3 different classes. But I think, that's not really good. So, the question is how to avoid this? Should I create one more class, where I can write all these constants and functions, and include this class? Maybe    there is another suggestions?

P.S. For example, functions like `abs` or `sign` and constants like `const int Scale = 50`

Comment: `abs` is already a standard function (use `<math.h>` or `<cmath>` then `fabs`). What is the `Scale` and why should it be a constant (not a tunable runtime parameter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't explain what are these constants.

I would make them some `#define`-d macro, e.g.

```
 #define MY_AVOGADRO 6.22e+23
```

or

```
 #define MY_FIRST_NAME "Basile"
```

YMMV. I agree that preprocessor macros are low-tech, but they are useful!

So have such `#define` inside some common header. Take the habit of using some common prefix. In that same header file, declare your global functions or define your `static inline` functions.

Alternatively, code something like

```
 const double my_avogadro = 6.22e+23;
```

You probably don't need to define a C++ `class` for this.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25544436/841108).

Comment: Macros remain the only solution for a few important tasks, such as #include, #ifdef and #if defined for conditional compilation. You should avoid macros, see C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices By Herb Sutter, Andrei Alexandrescu