# warning: 'visibility' attribute ignored - symbol visibility - C++/gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

Related topic:
[Why does const imply internal linkage in c++, when it doesn't in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c)

I was following [GCC visibility wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) to add visibility to my shared library.

It generates a warning when I'm compiling my source file

> warning: 'visibility' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]

Here's my code:

```
// my_shared_lib.h
#if __GNUC__ >= 4
    #define DLL_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
    #define DLL_LOCAL __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
#else
    #define DLL_API 
    #define DLL_LOCAL
#endif
DLL_LOCAL const int my_local_var;
```

It generate following warning while compiling:

```
my_shared_lib.h: 'visibility' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
DLL_LOCAL const int my_local_var;
               ^
```

Here's the entire building message:

```
make all
Building file: ../src/my_shared_lib.cc
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++-mp-4.8 -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/my_shared_lib.d" -MT"src/my_shared_lib.d" -o "src/my_shared_lib.o" "../src/my_shared_lib.cc"
my_shared_lib.h: 'visibility' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
DLL_LOCAL const int my_local_var;
               ^
Finished building: ../src/my_shared_lib.cc
```

Can anyone tell me how to silent this warning and why this warning happened?

Is it because `const variable` are `hidden` by default?

PS.
I'm using g++ 4.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can silence the warning by passing `-Wno-attributes` to the compilation.

The warning is happening because, as the related question and answer mentions, in `C++` const objects automatically have internal linkage unless they're explicitly marked as extern; i.e. they're hidden by default. The rationale is to encourage putting these `const` values into header files as-is (i.e. in the form `const int x = value;`). If they were public by default, then you would suffer multiple-linkage issues if the same variable appeared across multiple `.cpp` or `.o` files, which is what would happen if they were placed in `.h` files without the local linkage rule.

You should also be seeing a warning/error:

```
my_shared_lib.h:...: error: uninitialized const 'my_local_var' [-fpermissive]
```

which is a variation of the error because the const is implicitly static unless otherwise mentioned.

How do you fix this?

Firstly, use the `const` properly in the header when using `C++`, it's:

```
const int my_local_var = VALUE;
```

If you're sharing this `.h` file amongst `C` and `C++` code then your choices are:

1. Don't make it `const` - that's actually meaningless for the `C` code, and prevents you from accomplishing the private, declared in the header and defined in a `.c` file but not exposed in the resulting `.so`
2. Use a `#define` - yes, it's ugly, but this is more semantically correct than using a `const` for C code as it prevents you from accidentally changing the value by erroneous assignment.
3. declare it in the .h as:

...

```
DLL_LOCAL extern const int my_local_var;
```

and then define it in the `.cc`/`.cpp` file as:

```
 #include "my_shared_lib.h"

 const int my_local_var = 42;
```

You need to add in the `#include` or else it doesn't get the `extern` which allows it to be exposed for linking in the `.o` files that make up the `.so` without getting it exposed in the `.so` itself.

and so we have (on a mac, but the premise is the same):

Header:

```
$ cat wodge.h

#define PRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
#define PUBLIC __attribute__((visibility("default")))

PRIVATE extern const int my_local_var;
int do_with_x(int x);
```

First `C++` file:

```
$ cat wodge.cc

#include "wodge.h"

int
do_with_x(int y)
{
    return my_local_var * y;
}
```

Second `C++` file - definition of value:

```
$ cat wodge2.cc 
#include "wodge.h"

const int my_local_var = 42;
```

Compile and show the resulting symbol table:

```
$ g++-4.8 -c -O3 -Wall -o wodge.o wodge.cc
$ g++-4.8 -c -O3 -Wall -o wodge2.o wodge2.cc
$ g++-4.8 -shared -o foo.dylib *.o
$ nm foo.dylib
0000000000000fb0 T __Z9do_with_xi
0000000000000fbc s _my_local_var
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Comment: I believe this also applies to 'static'