# GCC linker complains about undefined reference to existing global variable

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld

I have a problem with GCC. It's unable to find my global variable. I created a sample C++ project to isolate the problem:

a.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"

const char * const g_test = "blah blah";

int main(){
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

b.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"

using namespace std;

void test(){
    cout << g_test;
}
```

a.h:

```
extern const char * const g_test;
```

b.h:

```
void test();
```

I compile it like this:

```
$ g++ -o a.o -c a.cpp
$ g++ -o b.o -c b.cpp
$ g++ -o test a.o b.o
b.o: In function `test()':
b.cpp:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `g_test'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Changing the order of object files in last command doesn't change anything.

Why does linker throw an error? I was expecting to just create an executable printing "blah blah", but somehow the error appears. I don't see any reason it should fail.

Comment: Doesn't `a.cpp` need to include `a.h`?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that consts have internal linkage in C++.

Comment: @Haatschii Wouldn't my string be included in the final binary two times?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c.

Comment: @NathanOliver Checked it, and it compiled. But I still don't understand why should I include it (definition is also a declaration)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a const variable `g_test` has only internal linkage, i.e. can only be used in the .cpp file it is defined. In order to give a const variable global linkage (i.e. make it usable from other source files) you have to add the `extern` keyword, i.e.:

```
#include "b.h"

extern const char * const g_test = "blah blah";

int main(){
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can include `a.h` at the beginning. In that case the `extern` forward declaration is known to the compiler when translating `a.cpp`.

The best solution however is to move the definition of `g_test` (without `extern` keyword ) into the header file. The reason being that in this way the compiler knows the definition of `g_test` in every compilation unit and is for example able to evaluate const expressions using it at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to add the keyword `extern` to your definition.  I know that looks weird, `extern` usually makes it a forward declaration and not a deffinition, but the compiler will still treat it as a definition (instantiation) because you give it a value.

The link in Quentin's comment [(stolen from Quentin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c) is a fantastic explanation of why.