# How come you don't need to assign a value to an extern const (int) when including it in a header file? in c++

Tags: c++

Usually when declaring a const of any sort you're supposed to assign a value to it immediately, but not in header files? why?

Comment: You're not supposed to make variables in header files at all (normal, global ones)

Comment: @deviantfan That's simply not true. Things like `const int MEANING = 42;` are perfectly OK in header files.

Comment: @NeilButterworth If you're ok with linker errors after including it multiple times...? edit: "normal"

Comment: @deviant You won't get any linker errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c

Comment: @samsas Post some code that illustrates what you are asking  about.

Comment: @NeilButterworth 3th time: "normal". WIthout any specifier.

Comment: @deviant  Your personal definition of the word "normal", I suppose?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage

Comment: @NeilButterworth Then what should I call it? "Variable without extern without const without constexpr without static without inline without..."? Sigh...

Comment: @deviantfan -- `const int MEANING = 42;` defines `MEANING` with **internal** linkage (because of the `const`),, so there is no problem putting it in a header file.

Answer (score 6):

It's because you declared it `extern`, extern tells the compiler that the definition and declaration of the variable are in another file and you are simply making your code "aware" of the existence of that variable, as such the compiler does not expect any assignment on the header.

Answer (score 2):

Remember not only you don't **need** to, but you shouldn't assign a value to `extern` declarations because that makes them a definition.