# const char* access: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, string, linker-errors

I have a header file `config.h` where I'm simply defining a string with a value using

```
namespace configuration {
    const char* name = "test";
}
```

And I access it from a `.cpp` file as `configuration::name`. But then I'm getting a compiler error:

```
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I change it to `const string name = "test";` it works. Why? And how do I fix this to be able to use a `const char*` instead?

Comment: `ld` should have also stated what it failed to link.

Comment: How are you accessing it in your `cpp` file? You might be trying to assign `const char*` to something that doesn't work with it whereas using `string` works.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado no, that's a linker error.

Comment: I just included config.h and accessed it via configuration::name

There are no other errors. That is all that was given.

Comment: [mcve], please.

Comment: Found a solution, fixed by changing it to: const char *const but can someone explain why this works?

Comment: @PahZon: Two lines above the `error: ld...` line, do you not see something like:  `/tmp/cc6c2o6v.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `configuration::name'`?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two strings

```
namespace config {
  const char* test1 = "test1";
  const std::string test2 = "test2";
}
```

is that the second is `const` and [hence has internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c), while the first is not (it's merely a pointer to a `const`) and requires external linkage, i.e. you must provide a definition in some .cpp file, failing of which causes your linker error.