# const causes a linker error for external file

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I have this cpp file which contains 2 arrays:

```
const float arr[123]={/*..*/};
const float ave[213]={/*..*/};
```

And in my main.cpp I have:

```
int main()
{
   extern float arr[123];
   float temp[123];
   for(unsigned i=0; i<123;i++)
      temp[i]=arr[i];
   return 0;
}
```

When I build my project I got an error saying that there’s no definition for arr.
It’s a linker error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Some reading on what you ran up against: [Why does const imply internal linkage in C++, when it doesn't in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Your `const` variable has internal linkage by default.
You need to declare it as `extern` as well to counteract that.