# Global variable and static global variable

Tags: c++, c++11, variables, global-variables, global

Is there any difference in C++ between global variable/const and global static variable/const? Declared in cpp file or a header file.

```
static const int x1 = someFunction(5);
const int x2 = someFunction(6);
static int x3 = someFunction(5);
int x4 = someFunction(6);

int main()
{
...
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: @cigien you closed mine and linked as a solution a question that doesn't have a solution.

Comment: Duplicate closures indicate that a question is a duplicate. Whether there are solutions on the target is not really relevant (apart from the minimum requirement that there be at least one upvoted answer on the target).

Comment: @cigien Anoop Rana's answer here is much better. And Kevin's answer provides good info.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I've found a better target though, and adjusted this question's target. That one addresses the question comprehensively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Case I: For const objects

##### Similarity

In both versions, the variables have **internal linkage**. That is, both `x1` and `x2` have *internal linkage*.

##### Difference

In case of `static const int x1` the variable is **explicitly static** while in case of `const int x2` the variable is **implicitly static**. But note that they both still have *internal linkage*.

#### Case II:For nonconst objects

##### Similarity

Both `x3` and `x4` are **nonconst** meaning we can modify them.

##### Difference

The variable `x3` has **internal linkage** while the variable `x4` has **external linkage**.

Comment: I've deleted my wrong answer because I missed that `const int x2` has internal linkage [because it's const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c). Just thought I'd mention it in a comment in case other people make that same mistake :)

Comment: @Kevin Yes i noticed that mistake in your answer.

Comment: @Kevin I haven't  seen your answer. Maybe you better undelete it? As I'm not only asking about const case, if there is a difference between const and non-const

Comment: Sure, I'll undelete it

Comment: @Random I have added the explanation for `nonconst` objects at the end of my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: This only applies when the variables aren't const. I've undeleted this answer at the OP's request**

`static int x1` has *internal linkage*, meaning it's only accessible by name from the translation unit it's defined in (this cpp file). If this line is in a header file, every file that includes the header will get its own copy of the variable.

`int x2` has *external linkage*, meaning another translation unit (cpp file) could have `extern int x2;` in global scope and access the variable. If this line is in a header file, and multiple files include the header, you're violating the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) since the variable is being defined once per include. You must instead use `extern int x2;` in the header, and then in a single cpp file have your `int x2 = ...;` to avoid multiple definitions.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration